# Find the slope of coordinates $(-7,-4)$ and $(-14,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the slope of coordinates $(-7,-4)$ and $(-14,3)$

I know how to do my problems. I just don't understand how I keep getting the fraction $1/7$.

Comment: **Hint:** $-(-a)=a$. As an aside, you can't find the slope of two points, but you can find the slope of the line that passes through those points. And this is quite far from *linear-algebra* (please read the description of it)

Answer (score 1):

$m = \frac{Y_2 - Y_1}{X_2 - X_1} = \frac{3-(-4)}{-14-(-7)} = \frac{7}{-7} = -1 $

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer, but I think this is spoonfeeding the  OP...

Comment: yes, you are right, I will keep in mind for my future answers